# select2 options are sorted but can not separate options by placing labels for each alphabet between options

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

i have sorted the options inside select2 but i want to display each alphabet before displaying its words.
My data contains raw words.

```
    $("#selectBox").select2({
        theme: "classic",
        sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)),
        placeholder: 'Select Name'
   });
```

[image]

In this image you can see the options are separated by dark words, i want same for each alphabets, display alphabet in dark color and then show words starting with that alphabet, and keep on doing same for all options.

I am using below data

```
'Ethics'
'Islam'
'Satisfaction of heart'
'Deeds'
'Bad Habit'
'Evil'
'Cowardice'
'Human '
'Rebellions'
'Water'
'Pure peace'
'Destiny'
'Rosary-1'
'Rosary-2'
'Monotheism-1'
'Monotheism-2'
'Arrogance'
'Creation of universal'
'Repentance'
'The virtue of jihad and Testimony'
'Magic'
'Hell-1'
'Hell-2'
'Hell-3'
'Forbidden'
'Hazrat Abrahim and Nimrod'
'Advices of Hazrat Luqman '
'Desire'
'Buying and Selling'
'Pray'
'Deception'
'It is haraam to show off'
'Zulqurnain and Yajooj and Majooj'
'Remembrance of Allah'
'Sustenance'
'Blessing'
'What is life'
'Interest'
'White heart and black heart'
'Devil'
'Devil is man\'s open enemy'
'Divorce'
'Thanks'
'Enmity'
```

Comment: Not getting what you mean here. Could you please a few examples to explain it in a better way. thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the data you use for these selection options?

Comment: i added the the data to my question, i select those directly from DB.